# Push a product click dataLayer event on Shopify with jQuery

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to push a dataLayer event for a product click in Shopify.
I can't figure out how to populate the product parameters when a product is clicked.

This is what I have but I don't think I am using the correct click event because no values come back? Is there a better way to do this?

```
  $('a[href*="/products/"]').click(function() {
                window.dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
                window.dataLayer.push({
                  event: "select_item",
                  ecommerce: {
                    items: [
                    {
                      item_id: '{{ product.id }}',
                      item_name: '{{ product.title | remove "'" | remove '"' }}',
                      index: , //not sure if I can capture this
                      item_brand: '{{ product.vendor }}',
                      item_category: 
                      item_list_id: '', 
                      item_list_name: '', 
                      price: '{{ product.selected_variant.price | money_without_currency }}',
                      quantity: 1
                    }
                    ]
                  }
                });;
                });
```

Comment: Where is `product` defined? Also, all the values in your items array object are just going to be treated as strings unless Shopify knows how to interpret the double-curlys `{{ }}`

Comment: The variables like {{product.id}} are part of the Shopify API and defined by Shopify. The variable names should be ok generally, but I think the way the action is triggering does not make these variable available to pull into the array.